# How to hide "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have error `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403` in browser console. How can I hide it? It is Ruby on Rails project and some urls for images are expired

Comment: hide it for you or for others?

Comment: for all users which will be on site and will open console

Comment: only option is to not load missing files; the console cannot be controlled by page script (other than log() et al)

Comment: thanks, how can I find out which file will not loaded?

Comment: you would have to do that server-side and somehow hand that blacklist off to the client.

Comment: The only way I could imagine this working is if you submit a request to a server-side script which then retrieves the requested file for you and, if it's found, returns that file/resource or if it cannot be found returns a default response which you can handle in your script. This way you can avoid the various errors - since the script should at least return a `200` header, along with any 'default' content or error messages held in a JSON file (or whatever).